# Can I use a script to sort the array fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index in elasticsearch structure like this：

```
{
  doc: {
    "my_field": [
      {
        "data": some_data,
        "date": "2021-09"
      },
      {
        "data": some_data,
        "date": "2021-10"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to sort this index using the data corresponding to the latest date.
I‘m trying to use script to solve this question like this:

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "script":{
          "source": "doc['my_field.data'][-1]"
        },
        "order": "desc",
        "type":"number"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

but the data doesn't corresponding to the latest date for `doc['my_field.data']` and `doc['my_field.date']`are actually two arrays in elasticsearch.
In this case, how could I solve my problem.

Comment: What is the type of field  "my_field". Is it object or nested type?

Comment: sort it at what point though, indexing or searching?